# Cocoapods causing error on latest Xcode 11.2.1 release

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have an Xcode project using Swift 5 on Catalina 10.15.1 and after updating Xcode to version 11.2.1 I am running into this error below when trying to do a pod update/install. It happens on various projects, so it doesn't appear to be specific to one project. Does anyone know what might be the cause and how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Try [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6574) yet? `gem uninstall cocoapods`  -> `gem cleanup` -> `gem install cocoapods`. If unlucky, try update gem: `gem update --system`

Comment: @TraiNguyen Yep, tried all of that. Tried reinstalling Xcode as well. Still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1 :- Open your terminal.

step 2:-  ( command :- sudo gem install cocoapods. )

step 3: - open project folder in terminal.

step 4:- command :- pod install.

**Hope this will solve your problem**

Comment: This time I deleted the ~/.cocoapods/repos folder and then ran that and it works now.

Comment: I could not find a solution tried many other things including this one.... re installing Xcode 11.2.1 worked for me.